# How to make SQL server 2000 compatible with SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to dump a software to a clients server. The problem is that my software is using SQL server 2008 and the client is using SQL Server 2000. So could anyone please suggest how I can make the clients SQL server 2000 compatible with my queries of SQL server 2008?

Thanks for the suggestion

But my concern is that software is already developed with SQL server 2008, then is there any way to use it with SQL server 2000?

Comment: You need to make your queries compatible with SQL 2000, not the other way around.

Comment: If you didn't develop this software for this client alone you should define requirements for your software.

Comment: You'd better ask why the client is still using SQL Server 2000 and is unwilling to upgrade, it is entirely unsupported (no bug fixes (since 2008) nor security updates (since last year)).

Comment: Oh FFS. This is like asking "I have a program that needs Windows 7 but I have Windows 95. How do I make Windows 95 compatible with Windows 7?" Face it, in that case, no amount of changes to Windows settings is going to make that program work. You *need* the newer version of Windows. Why would it be any different for SQL Server?

Answer (score 4):

1. You should have developed your software against SQL 2000, or demanded your client upgrade to at least 2005. Did
   you ask the client which version you would deploy to before starting development? That is part of **standard requirements gathering**.
2. SQL 2008 queries may or may not be compatible with SQL 2000 due to
   many new features in 2005 and 2008. There is no shortcut.
3. At best, make sure to use SQL 2000 documentation from MSDN when writing queries. Use the lowest common denominator.
4. If you are supporting a product that must deploy to multiple SQL Server versions, you may consider using an ORM that supports SQL 2000. Checkout the Nuget gallery of ORMs: http://staging.nuget.org/packages?q=Tags%3A%22ORM%22 - I believe something simple like Dapper supports 2000.

At minimum you should set your SQL 2008 compatibility level down to 2000 during development.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 80
```

I recommend you setup a virtual machine, install the older OS that your client uses as well as SQL Server 2000. Otherwise there are unforeseeable differences.

Comment: Setting the compatibility level still wont catch all problems though, but it is a good start.

Comment: Can i use any tool at clients machine to make their SQL server 2000 to compatible with my developed software in SQL server 2008?

Comment: No. It seems you skipped the step of defining requirements before starting development.